# PerWebRequest and Transient lifeStyles

Tags: castle-windsor

Can someone please help me understand several things?

1. Do I still have to register PerRequestModule to use
   LifeStylePerWebRequest? I use Castle.Windsor 3.2.0.0 and it seems
   everything works without this module. I definetly remember that
   there was an exception before that tells me "You forget to register
   this module".
2. What "objects tracked by release policy" really
   means? I use several Components with LifeStyleTransient but when I
   Resolve one I get it in "objects tracked by release policy"
   property, when I Resolve others I don't get them there.
3. How can I check the actual objects stored inside the container (and their
   number)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) I guess since version 3.x PerRequestModule will be automatically registered by windsor.

2) An object will be tracked by windsor only [if needed](http://kozmic.net/2010/08/19/must-windsor-track-my-components/)(for ex if its lifestyle is Transient and it implements IDisposable interface).

3) You can run unit tests checking for handlers or manually set a debug point once you registered all components and navigate with VS viewer container object: it has a property that lists all registered components.